# How to detect Exif String encoding

Tags: android, exif, android-exifinterface

I'm trying to get the exif of user comment using native Android API associated with `ExifInterface.TAG_USER_COMMENT`

this value should return a `String` but unfortunately seems that the `String` is encoded in some way.

E.g. if I get the user comment TAG of [this image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fEWdDxbEfEC51nMYFSAvhFi9rTEK0xlX/view?usp=sharing) I get this `String`:

> MNS G16 IN10 N5 O1.00 Y0.00 C0.00 YT0 CT0 s0 sY1.00 S350 C20   FM0 
>   FC111011001:zzzzzz0 b194 0278044079c3f65883c014c0 bac1061ea 3d
>   3d357250294  0  0  0  0 0 0 0 0294 182 130 60 5 1287 180 121 5e 5 1288
>   cb  a5 5e 0 0292  f2  cc 61ff 029c 158 121 5f 5 02a6 192 141 5e 5 02b0
>   1d5 175 60 5 02ba 1ef 188 60 5 02c4 200 178 5e 5 02ce 1d4 15a 5c 5
>   02ba 168 134 5f 5 0535b535b535b535b4840484048404840 f f f f f f f
>   f23202320232023201a321a321a321a323c373c373c373c37 e e e e e e e
>   e1718171817181718181b181b181b181b138813881388138813881388138813881388138813881388138813881388138813881388138813881388138813881388138813881388138813881388138813881388138813881388138813881388138813881388138813881388138813881388138813881388138813881388138813881388138813881388138813881388138813881388138813881388138813881388138813881388138813881388138813881388138813881388138813881388138813881388138813881388138813881388138813881388138813881388138813881388138813881388138813881388138813881388138813881388138813881388138813881388138813881388138813881388138813881388138813881388138813881388138813881388138813881388

How should I handle the result in order to get an human readable text?

Comment: Which `ExifInterface` implementation are you using? There are three of them. BTW, `exiftool` on the desktop reports the same cryptic tag content, so my guess the problem is in how the image was created, not in `ExifInterface`. What is that tag supposed to contain?

Comment: @CommonsWare now I'm using `androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface` but also with previous support library I get same result.

Comment: The TAG should contain an User Comment. So some textual note about the image.

Comment: How is that tag being set? http://metapicz.com also shows the same tag content, so that image really has that tag, and you would need to ask whoever is creating the tag how to decode it.

Comment: @CommonsWare I don't know. Isn't there some way to detect the String encoding used? Exif is a standardized format so I guess the encoding that could be used should be limited.

Comment: My guess is that the User Comment tag can be anything. However, your question suggests that the problem is with `ExifInterface`, and that is not the case.

Comment: I have edited the question.